# 4 floats to determine a plane?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am taking up a programming and asked to create a function for a certain problem. I was given this struct for a plane. However I can't make sense of this struct. How can 4 floats determine a plane in 3d space?

```
// plane in 3d space
struct Plane
{
    float A;
    float B;
    float C;
    float D;
};
```

Comment: A plane has equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ for some reals $A,B,C,D$

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thanks. Any more ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible to use 4 floats to define a plane, as David Peterson's comment shows. But, without some documentation, it's impossible to say **what** plane the four floats define. So, for example, the four floats $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ could define the plane
$$
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
$$
or the plane 
$$
Ax + By + Cz = D
$$
or the plane 
$$
Dx + Cy + Bz = A
$$
or any number of other planes.

In general, a data structure doesn't *mean* anything, by itself -- you need some semantic information.

Comment: So i just added a comment in the code saying it assumes this formula: Ax+By+Cz+D=0. I think it would be ok. :)